# How to run MS SQL Server commands from Sublime Text (Mac)?

Tags: sql, macos, sql-server-2008, sublimetext

I'm looking for a way to run sql commands and sql queries from Sublime Text on Mac OSX using SQL Server 2008.  I'd like to be able to do this on my Mac.  Anybody have success doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please link to some "similar versions" of this question? What did you try so far that didn't work?

Comment: @mattdmo This answer is related but it doesn't look like anybody found a way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298978/microsoft-sql-server-in-sublime-text-2.  I've tried TSQLEasy Sublime plugin but that appears to require PYODC on Windows or Linux.  This tutorial looked promising but only works with Windows or Ubuntu https://medium.com/@vin.yu/execute-t-sql-queries-with-sublime-text-da9906295be5#.5sgfexqnp